# What's the easiest way to free up disk space on my iMac with a huge photo library?

Tags: imac, hard-drive, photos.app, disk-space

This is a hybrid hardware/software question with a few more factors than the typical "freeing disk space" question.

I have an older iMac with (I think) about a 250 GB hard drive. It's been running out of disk space for a while, and each time I find some way to recover a bit more room. I've used DaisyDisk, etc. to identify large unused files, moved my iPhone/iPad backups to cloud, etc.

At this point there's just one big culprit left: our iPhoto library, which has been fed increasingly large photos. (iPhone 4S + Nikon DSLR -> way more megapixels than my earliest photos!) The iPhoto library hogs most of the space now and I'd like to avoid one-by-one reviewing & deleting photos if I can help it.

Is there a software solution? Can I tell iPhoto to archive the oldest photos to a NAS? (I have plenty of network space) And if I do that, will photos take longer to open?

Is there a hardware solution? For instance, if I buy a Time Capsule is there a one-step way to relocate my existing photo library? And again, will it slow down the use of photos on my machine and/or prevent me from seeing all of my albums?

Also, I'd like to start moving some of my music back to the iMac - any solution that will let me do the same for iTunes (keep some local, move some to network storage) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your NAS is always available and connected to your iMac, you can move both iPhoto and iTunes libraries to the NAS and use

- symbolic links from `~/Pictures` and `~/Music` to fool the applications
- start the application with <kbd>Option</kbd> pressed to select the alternative location
- iTunes: select alternative storage location in Options
- iPhoto: start by double-clicking moved library file

Comment: You shouldn't need the symbolic links. iTunes allows you to set the path to its Library. iPhoto can be opened by double-clicking on a Library file, and will use that file as its default until you open another. Unfortunately, neither provides a solution for splitting a library across storage locations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I've edited the answer accordingly.