# Cloud storage options for iPhoto's primary storage (not for backups)

Tags: macos, photos.app

My wife and I both have Macbook Airs with relatively limited internal hard disks. If we could just offload our iPhoto libraries, we'd be fine.

What are some of the cloud storage options for iPhoto? Meaning, when I open iPhoto, everything feels local, but is really stored in the cloud.

Note:

1. [This thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48224/whats-the-easiest-way-to-free-up-disk-space-on-my-imac-with-a-huge-photo-librar) talks about wireless NAS as an option, which might
   be a better way to go.
2. I'm talking about using the cloud as primary storage, **not as a
   backup.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to wait for the release of [Photos for OS X Yosemite](http://www.imore.com/photos-os-x-yosemite-explained), which is going to replace iPhoto early next year and will do exactly what you're asking for.

You'll be able to store all of your photos in iCloud, and the Photos app will dynamically cache only the most recent and/or frequently accessed photos locally, freeing up lots of disk space.

Pricing will be 99¢/month for 20 GB or $3.99/month for 200 GB (or 5 GB for free, but that's really not much). There's also going to be a 1 TB option, but Apple hasn't announced pricing yet.

OS X Yosemite and the new Photos app will both be free updates, and will run on any MacBook Air released in late 2008 or later (which is every model other than the very first one).

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need. They also say the photos in iCloud will be backed up (though I like having local backups) and will enable family sharing--would love to have a single iPhoto library shared across all our machines that we can all add to.